# I tried to open anaconda navigator but following error keeps poping: " ImportError: cannot import name 'raise_from' "

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I tried to open anaconda navigator using terminal "anaconda-navigator" but following error keeps popping up:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'raise_from' ".`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 32, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/client_api.py", line 20, in <module>
    import binstar_client
  File "/home/anupam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/binstar_client/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six import raise_from
ImportError: cannot import name 'raise_from'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I had reinstalled a higher version of the package six (1.7). When I uninstalled that and installed 1.1x, it worked.